# Integrating HTML5 into native iPad application

Tags: javascript, ios, html

I am trying to integrate a **webpage** into an iPad application.  Something like the Final Hour app where the app is a native app using slideshows.  some of the slideshow pages have a small part that is loaded from a website.

The only way I would have known this was when I didn't have internet access the small area where the website loads into said there was no internet connection.

How can I implement something like this?  I understand the website aspect but I don't understand what iOS API they use to setup some sort of canvas or frame to hold the website.

Here is an image of the app.  The webpage would be loaded into the "blue" box outline.

[image]

Comment: You want to use an UIWebview?

Comment: yes. so does that load the whole website and act as if it's a mini browser?

Comment: @FreeLancer The browser controls are up to you to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed looking for a [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/).  You need to build the controls yourself if you want your users to navigate in the website. If you just want to show one page, with no Back or Reload button, then you can use it as is.

Note that you should try to make it clear to your users that your app might not work properly if no Internet connection is available.